How to send an email with Exchange On-Premises in outlook addin
I am building a outlook addin  where I need to send an email for phishing to specific exchange account using Exchange On-Premises via Exchange Web Services (EWS). I am trying to make a POST request to the EWS endpoint from the frontend, but I’m facing issues with connectivity and authentication.
What I’ve tried:
EWS Endpoint: https://exchange.example.com/ews/Exchange.asmx
Authentication: I am using basic authentication with a username and password. The request is sent with an XML body in the POST request.
Error: I’m encountering a ConnectTimeoutError and fetch failed error while trying to connect to the server from the React app.
const sendEmail = async () => {
  const EXCHANGE_URL = "https://exchange.example.com/ews/Exchange.asmx";
  const USERNAME = "user@example.com";
  const PASSWORD = "password";

  const xmlPayload = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <soap:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2016" />
      </soap:Header>
      <soap:Body>
        <m:CreateItem xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
          <m:Items>
            <t:Message>
              <t:Subject>Test Email</t:Subject>
              <t:Body BodyType="Text">This is a test email sent via EWS from React frontend.</t:Body>
              <t:ToRecipients>
                <t:Mailbox>
                  <t:EmailAddress>recipient@example.com</t:EmailAddress>
                </t:Mailbox>
              </t:ToRecipients>
            </t:Message>
          </m:Items>
        </m:CreateItem>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>`;

  try {
    const response = await fetch(EXCHANGE_URL, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/xml",
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(`${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}`)
      },
      body: xmlPayload,
    });

    const data = await response.text();
    console.log("Email sent successfully:", data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error connecting to Exchange:", error);
  }
};

sendEmail();



What type of addin are you trying to build ? if its an old Com+ based addin then don't use EWS you better of just using the OOM to send it. With the newer addin framework you would normally use a Callback tokens https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/authentication?redirectedfrom=MSDN#callback-tokens and then use makeEwsRequestAsync https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services this means the Auth and routing/discovery are all handled for you.
You could start with testing EWS using the EWSeditor https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor/releases that allows you to test the authentication and connectivity outside of any code your writing.

I am Using Exchange On premises
